# perform group actions without reducing to one row

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that contains an ID and some additional data. I want to perform transformations based on the ID with a `by statement`. The transformation works. Unfortunately SAS automatically reduces the dataset to one row per group. Does anybody know how to keep the original (number of) rows and still perform the group actions?

Here is some sample code to illustrate my problem

```
    data dat;              
   input ID X $; 
   datalines;  
1 a
1 b
1 c
1 d
2 a
2 b
3 a
4 k
5 z
5 a
5 c
; 

data dat_new;
   length x_new $2100.;
   do until(last.ID);
       set dat;
       by ID notsorted;
       x_new = ',' ||catx(',',x,x_new);
   end; 
   drop x;
run;
```

Comment: it depends do you want the final value added to all rows or a more 'running' value type style. If you move the do loop to after SET you get the latter. The Do loop around the SET statement is a less used method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an OUTPUT statement inside the DO loop.

```
data dat_new;
   length x_new $2100.;
   do until(last.ID);
       set dat;
       by ID notsorted;
       x_new = ',' ||catx(',',x,x_new);
       output;
   end; 
   drop x;
run;
```

When you do not have an explicit OUTPUT statement in a data step then an implied OUTPUT statement executes at the end of the data step.  Your DO loop around the SET statement means that the end of the data step is only reached for the last observation per group.

If you want the final calculated value to be replicated on each observation then just add another loop to re-read the observations and put the OUTPUT statement in that loop.

```
data dat_new;
   length x_new $2100.;
   do until(last.ID);
       set dat;
       by ID notsorted;
       x_new = ',' ||catx(',',x,x_new);
   end; 
   do until(last.ID);
       set dat;
       by ID notsorted;
       output;
   end;
   drop x;
run;
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. I think I will never really get the SAS programming logic, but as long as there is someone around to ask .... :D

Answer (score 1):

When you want to associate a group level computation result to EACH row in the group you will need to first iterate over the group to compute the result, and then have a second loop that reads the same rows of the group and outputs each.  Use additional variables if you need to know the sequence number within the group and the total number of rows in the group.

```
data want(keep=id x_csv_list by_group_size seq);
   length x_csv_list $2100.;
   do by_group_size = 1 by 1 until(last.ID);
       set dat;
       by ID notsorted;
       x_csv_list = catx(',',x_csv_list,x);
   end; 
   do seq = 1 to by_group_size;
       set dat;
       output;
   end;
run;
```

Also, if you are at the 'never really get it' stage, remember `NOTSORTED` means contiguous rows with the same `by` group variable values.

```
  by s
s group  first.s  last.s
- -----  -------  ------
A 1st      1        0
A 1st      0        0   /* trick knowledge both 0 means row is interior */
A 1st      0        1

B 2nd      1        1   /* trick knowledge both 1 means group size is 1 row */

A 3rd      1        0
A 3rd      0        1

B 4th      1        0
B 4th      0        0
B 4th      0        1

C 5th      1        0
C 5th      0        1
```